# obscurity about session_destroy

Tags: php, session, cookies, destroy

i have searched and searched and read and read a lot about what exactly session_destroy does ! but no result at least for me ! first read the details below :

> When a session is created (session_start) a file is created with a
>   unique identifier that is given to the user as a cookie, when
>   variables in the $_SESSION array are modified or added the temporary
>   file is updated with that information so that it can be used somewhere
>   else on the website.*
>
> session_destroy* will delete this file, this is commonly done for when
>   a user logs out of your website so that the (now useless and
>   unnecessary) file isn't taking up space.

we know that session id is stored in session cookie and as the tutorials say , session destroy removes the session cookie file (that includes session_id ) so why when i started a new session it didn't generate a new id ! it makes me confused ! look at the example :

```
<?php
    session_start();
     echo session_id();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();

     echo "---".session_id();
?>
```

result : l4k80dkrl5kd6cdlobhbu5s3i1---l4k80dkrl5kd6cdlobhbu5s3i1

so it gives me the session id same as the previous one .

so what does session_destroy really do !! ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP documentation:

> It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the
>   session, or unset the session cookie.

So after `session_destroy()` the cookie that holds the session id is still alive, and just the session file will be deleted. So `start_session()` tries to find the file for the session id in the cookie, and it fails of course, and it just creates a new empty file for that. So your id does not change.

If you really want to change that, try to delete the cookie.

Comment: So, what is session file ?

Comment: Session file we are talking about is a regular file created on the server side, cookies are stored on client side ... come on guys!

Comment: Some text files, holding the session data, on the server

Comment: and where is this session file exactly stored !?

Comment: It varies on different servers. You can get it by `session_save_path()`

Comment: uhum! thanks ! just one more thing , what is in that file!?

Comment: Just session variables, in a special format. Open one of them and you will see

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct about what you have said, *BUT* if you destroy the session and the script ends in PHP, thats the time file is deleted. If you just try to destroy and create it again, it uses the same file/session ID.

Its not only the file that is created, but also the file contains all the data you are storing in the session. Have a look at your session data in your server, its very interesting.

**Update**
More interesting things you can do. Write a PHP file

```
<?php
session_start();
sleep(29000);//delete the session after 29 seconds
session_destroy();
?>
```

Now have a look at the session file, it should be deleted after 20 seconds.

Do

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and go to google chrome, and remove the cookie manually from there. The session won't be available anymore.

> `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` will not destroy the cookies on the
>   client side. Next time you create a session, it will just use the same
>   old information. This is the prime reason of your question.

Do
file1:

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['test'] = "A"; ?>
```

file2:

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['test'] = "B"; ?>
```

resultFile:

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['test']; ?>
```

Now from two computers, access your website with file1 on one computer and file2 on another. From google chrome, switch their cookie information and see how session A is assigned to B and B is assigned to A.

Comment: So why should this happen ? When I have removed session cookie with session destroy ! How does it retrieve  the session id ?

Comment: How did you remove the session cookie?

Comment: By calling session_destroy

Comment: session_destroy() doesn't remove the cookie (or any other source of the session id). see http://docs.php.net/session_destroy

Comment: As I've read in internet session destroy removes the files which session id is in it (session cookie)

Comment: `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` will not destroy the cookies on the client side. Next time you create a session, it will just use the same old information. This is the prime reason of your question.

Comment: `session destroy removes the files which session id ...(session_cookie)` - no it does not. session_destroy removes the file (or whatever storage is configured) on the server; that's the file holding the session data, more or less what you find in _SESSION. It also removes the data that is currently used by the session module. But it does not affect client data nor request data. Esp. the latter is the reason why you get the same sesion_id when calling session_start again. But the data (on the server <-> _SESSION) associated with this session_id is gone.

Comment: VolkerK is right session_destroy clears the memory used by the $_SESSION array Note C code off PHP---> `ZVAL_UNDEF(&PS(http_session_vars));` is called within `php_rinit_session_globals()` and `php_rshutdown_session_globals()`what is used in the `session_destroy()` and it also calles the session handler close function with `PS(mod)->s_close(&PS(mod_data));` within the function `php_rshutdown_session_globals`